# Can’t pair Magic Keyboard due to numerical keys not working

Tags: keyboard, imac, bluetooth

I bought a iMac 27” off eBay and included in the sale was an Apple trackpad and Magic Keyboard.

I am trying to pair the keyboard but when the screen asks me to enter the numerical confirmation code, the number keys on the keyboard do not work.

The trackpad paired perfectly though.

I have plugged in a wired USB keyboard and everything works fine there.

Have I inadvertently activated a keyboard shortcut on the Magic Keyboard and disabled number keys or something?

Can I hard reset the keyboard back to factory settings?

Comment: Do the numeric keys work when paired with a different machine

Comment: The number keys along the top should work just to pair it. Then troubleshoot the number keypad. What else have you tried? Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your replies. I just tried pairing it with my windows 10 PC and again the same problem, I couldn’t enter the passcode as the number keys wouldn’t work. Also, it was labelled “Roberts Keyboard” as opposed to “Apple Magic Keyboard” which I thought was weird, is it paired to another machine? Can I hard reset this thing? It’s the earlier magic keyboard with only number keys at the top, no dedicated keypad on the right side like the newer model. I’m completely baffled 

Answer (score 1):

You should able to connect the keyboard to your Mac with a lightning cable. When you unplug it again, it should be paired. Note that it won’t be listed as (Bluetooth) paired whilst connected with a cable, but it should still be usable in that state.

Once paired, you can rename it in the Bluetooth settings.

Comment: It is the Apple magic keyboard 1, the model without a lightning connector so I can’t do that 

Comment: Update: I turned the keyboard on and then the Mac and when trying to pair, I have realised that the 0 number and Enter key work, but no others. What does his mean?